# Sails JS: default forbidden response loads default layout

Tags: sails.js

I'm using Sails v0.10.5.

For some reason, when the error page 403.ejs is loaded (by forbidden.js) it is included in the default layout under views/layout.ejs.

What I get is 403.ejs included in layout.ejs therefore:

```
<html> 
    ... 
    <html> 
        ... 
    </html> 
    ... 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All views will use the layout.ejs file.

This is done so that you can customize the your response files and they too will also use the layout.

You can set a local variable `layout` within the response so that the layout file does not render.

In your responses/forbidden.js, look where the locals is defined and set `locals.layout = false` or you can set it to a custom layout file